# Disable (hide from tray) "Safely remove hardware" for particular external (usb) hdd

Tags: windows-7, laptop, usb, external-hard-drive, safely-remove-hardware

I'm using external hdd as one of prime hdd for my laptop (with windows 7). It is always plugged in. But as it is plugged into the usb port, it shows in "Safely remove hardware". Sometimes I missclick it when trying to unplug flash drive.

Is there a way to hide particular device from that devices list? Or a way to make usb port as internal one? I know there is solution for SATA/AHCI, but didn't found any for usb.

[My laptop - MSI GP62 6QF(Leopard Pro)-1605XRU](https://us.msi.com/Laptop/GP62-6QF-Leopard-Pro.html#hero-overview).

Comment: [Flipping the Removable Media bit -- alternatives to BootIt?](//superuser.com/q/391176)

Comment: @DavidPostill, seems like answer. So there is no legit/right way to do it. Pretty bad I must say.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the cache on the drive. The safety remove hardware message is because the drive has a cache turned on that causes your data to sit in RAM before it is written to the drive. If there is an improper removal, your data will be lost. But, having the cache improves performance.

You can disable write-caching under the properties menu of the drive. Open My Computer and right-click the drive in question. Click properties. Under the policies tab, disable write caching or choose Quick Removal under removal policy.

Comment: "If there is an improper removal, your data will be lost" - but if there is improper removal with/without enabled, data still will be lost, won't it?

Comment: Cache was initially disabled. Anyway, tried to enable it and disable with restarts. Still shows in tray.

Comment: I just tested this on Windows 7 myself, and it does not work. Sorry, it has been a while since I played with these settings. Maybe this was a Windows XP thing. It doesn't look like this behavior can be reliably changed. See here for an alternative, but not perfect, workaround that involves changing mount points: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/83ba2cb3-822b-41fe-8fc8-9c2f3b8b418c/is-there-any-way-to-hide-a-device-from-safely-remove-hardware-and-eject-media?forum=w7itproui

Comment: In regards to your question about data still being lost on improper removal. You would be right if the drive was actively being written to. But, disabling write caching forces the data to be written out to the drive immediately, rather than sitting in memory for extended periods of time and potentially being lost. That is the difference.

Comment: this does not help at all, what made you think this would work in the first place?